# Which tools i can use to load the Android Sdk works fast in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin, android-2.2-froyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

I am using Eclipse to load the Android project and work on it.
but it seems that the loading project and during building it, it takes some time.

So what should i have to do to run it fast ?
The Configuration of My CPU is:

- OS: Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition N
- Intel(R) Core(TM)i3 CPU
- 540 @3.07GHz
- 3.06GHz, 3.17 GB of RAM

Please guide me for this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install Android SDK as well as Eclipse other than C: drive,
Then check the CPU process in Task Manager whether any other software might take more RAM process which leads to take more time for Eclipse.
And one more thing, close unnecessary projects in Eclipse, Open only required project, Since while building, eclipse will try to compile all the projects which you have open in Package Explorer.